# Sum data from two tables with different number of rows

Tags: sql

There are 3 Tables (SorMaster, SorDetail, and InvWarehouse):

**SorMaster:**

```
+------------+
| SalesOrder |
+------------+
|    100     |
|    101     |
|    102     |
+------------+
```

**SorDetail:**

```
+------------+------------+---------------+
| SalesOrder | MStockCode | MBackOrderQty |
+------------+------------+---------------+
|    100     |    PN-1    |       4       |
|    100     |    PN-2    |       9       |
|    100     |    PN-3    |       1       |
|    100     |    PN-4    |       6       |
|    101     |    PN-1    |       6       |
|    101     |    PN-3    |       2       |
|    102     |    PN-2    |      19       |
|    102     |    PN-3    |      14       |
|    102     |    PN-4    |       6       |
|    102     |    PN-5    |       4       |
+------------+------------+---------------+
```

**InvWarehouse:**

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+
| MStockCode | Warehouse | QtyOnHand |
+------------+-----------+-----------+
|    PN-1    |     A     |     1     |
|    PN-2    |     B     |     9     |
|    PN-3    |     A     |     0     |
|    PN-4    |     B     |     1     |
|    PN-1    |     A     |     0     |
|    PN-3    |     B     |     5     |
|    PN-2    |     A     |     9     |
|    PN-3    |     B     |     4     |
|    PN-4    |     A     |     6     |
|    PN-5    |     B     |     0     |
+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Desired Results:

```
+------------+-----------------+--------------+
| MStockCode | SumBackOrderQty | SumQtyOnHand |
+------------+-----------------+--------------+
|    PN-1    |       10        |      10      |
|    PN-2    |       28        |       1      |
|    PN-3    |       17        |       5      |
|    PN-4    |       12        |      13      |
|    PN-5    |       11        |       6      |
+------------+-----------------+--------------+
```

I have been going around in circles with no end in sight. Seems like it should be simple but just can't wrap my head around it. The SumBackOrderQty obviously getting counted twice as the SumQtyOnHand is evaluated. To this point I have been doing the calculations in the PHP instead of the select statement but would like to clean things up a bit where possible.

**Current query statement is:**

```
SELECT  SorDetail.MStockCode,
    SUM(SorDetail.MBackOrderQty) AS 'SumMBackOrderQty',
    SUM(InvWarehouse.QtyOnHand) AS 'SumQtyOnHand'

FROM    SysproCompanyJ.dbo.SorMaster SorMaster,
    SysproCompanyJ.dbo.SorDetail SorDetail LEFT OUTER JOIN SysproCompanyJ.dbo.InvWarehouse InvWarehouse
    ON SorDetail.MStockCode = InvWarehouse.StockCode


WHERE   SorMaster.SalesOrder = SorDetail.SalesOrder
    AND SorMaster.ActiveFlag != 'N'
    AND SorDetail.MBackOrderQty > '0'
    AND SorDetail.MPrice > '0'

GROUP BY SorDetail.MStockCode

ORDER BY    SorDetail.MStockCode ASC
```

Comment: Sum each table in a subquery, and then join them.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? MySQL, Oracle, SQL-Server? Please add the appropriate tag to the question.

Comment: Since you don't have a column common to all three tables you can't use a `JOIN`, this is the main problem for performing this in one query as you will not be ablte to run a `SUM` operator in a subquery. I believe your choices are to either to run 2 separate queries and perform the addition in `PHP` once you've stored the data in associative key => value pairs or else add the `SalesOrder` column to all 3 tables

Comment: How do you calculate the desired results from the sample data?  I cannot figure out any way to get quantity on hand.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I presume it has something to do with the `WHERE`-clause, which is referencing columns that aren't present in the sample data provided

Comment: How `SumBackOrderQty` of `PN-5` is `11` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without providing the complete picture, in terms of your RDBMS, database schema, a description of the problem you're trying to solve and sample data that matches the aforementioned, the following is just an illustration of what a solution based on Barmar's comment could look like:

```
SELECT SD.MStockCode, 
       SD.SumBackOrderQty, 
       IW.SumQtyOnHand
FROM (SELECT MStockCode, 
             SUM(MBackOrderQty) AS `SumBackOrderQty`
      FROM SorDetail
           JOIN SorMaster ON SorDetail.SalesOrder=SorMaster.SalesOrder
      WHERE SorMaster.ActiveFlag != 'N'
            AND SorDetail.MBackOrderQty > 0
            AND SorDetail.MPrice > 0
      GROUP BY MStockCode) AS SD
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT MStockCode, 
                       SUM(QtyOnHand) AS `SumQtyOnHand`
                FROM InvWarehouse
                GROUP BY MStockCode) AS IW ON SD.MStockCode=IW.MStockCode
ORDER BY SD.MStockCode;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

```
select MStockCode, 
(select sum(MBackOrderQty) from sorDetail as T2
where T2.MStockCode = T1.MStockCode ) as SumBackOrderQty,
(select sum(QtyOnHand) from invWarehouse as T3
where T3.MStockCode = T1.MStockCode ) as SumQtyOnHand 
from 
(
select mstockcode from sorDetail
union
select mstockcode from invWarehouse
) as T1
```

In a fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fdaca/6

Though my `SumQtyOnHand` values don't match yours (as @Gordon pointed out).